# Flask WTForms disabling multiple fields with multiple buttons

Tags: javascript, python, flask, wtforms

I have a form in Flask made with WTForms. It includes 3 checkboxes, and 9 other fields. 7 of those fields are disabled if one out of the three checkboxes are ticked.

Here is just a small sample of a checkbox, a field that is disabled when the checkbox is ticked, and also the OptionalIf class that makes the selected field optional if the checkbox is ticked:

```
class OptionalIf(Optional):

    def __init__(self, otherFieldName, *args, **kwargs):
        self.otherFieldName = otherFieldName
        #self.value = value
        super(OptionalIf, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def __call__(self, form, field):
        otherField = form._fields.get(self.otherFieldName)
        if otherField is None:
            raise Exception('no field named "%s" in form' % self.otherFieldName)
        if bool(otherField.data):
            super(OptionalIf, self).__call__(form, field)
```

Inside my form class:

```
holiday = BooleanField('Holiday?', id="holiday", validators=[Optional()])
start_time = TimeField(label='Start Time', id='timepick1', format='%H:%M', validators=[OptionalIf('holiday'), OptionalIf('holiday_noAddedHours'), OptionalIf('sick')])
```

The `holiday_noAddedHours` and `sick` are the other checkbox fields, that each have their own ID: `holidayNAH` and `sick`.

As there are seven fields to be disabled, I have to have this within my scripts:

```
document.getElementById('holiday').onchange = function(){
  document.getElementById('timepick1').disabled = this.checked;
  document.getElementById('timepick2').disabled = this.checked;
  ....
}
document.getElementById('holidayNAH').onchange = function(){
  document.getElementById('timepick1').disabled = this.checked;
  document.getElementById('timepick2').disabled = this.checked;
  ....
}
```

And then another one for the `sick` ID.

I was wondering if it was possible to shorten this, instead of having 3 `document.getElementById`s and seven lines within that disabling the fields if the box is checked? I understand that having one ID is not possible as it `getElementById` gets the first element, so how would I go about this?

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a for loop over a list of the id's you want to change. For example:

```
all_ids = ['timepick1', 'timepick2'];


for (i=0; i<all_ids.length; i++){
    document.getElementById(all_ids[i]).disabled = this.checked;
}
```